# Identifying a user who rename tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

The unauthorized table renaming is causing SQL agent jobs to fail, and we don't know who is renaming those tables. Is there a way to identify who renamed a particular table like (maybe using a System_user or any other).

I am looking to implement a system/process that will log if tables or procs or views are renamed it will log the information of the user who did that. I am using SQL 2017.

Comment: Well, you call it "unauthorized table renaming" but clearly you have given some user more rights than needed. No normal user should have access to make changes to table structures. I'd say you should go through your security list and make sure users only have the access right they should have.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Schema Changes Report for the database under Standard Reports.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tested that rename events show up on this?